# Newsstand daily update content at background

Tags: ios, background, newsstand-kit, uibackgroundtask

My app should have auto-download the newsstand content every day but it will only started only when I launch the app normally. I am completely new on using Newsstand app. Have I missed out anything for this?

I have ticked the "Newsstand Download" in Background Modes's capabilities.

Info.plist

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>newsstand-content</string>
</array>
```

I am putting this in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** and **didReceiveRemoteNotification**

```
NSString *issueName = [pdf lastPathComponent];
NKLibrary *library = [NKLibrary sharedLibrary];

if (![library issueWithName:issueName]) {
    NKIssue *issue = [library addIssueWithName:issueName date:pdf.newsDate];

    NKAssetDownload *asset = [issue addAssetWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pdf.pdf]]];
    [asset downloadWithDelegate:self];

}
```

Is there a good way to test this? I am currently wait every day to see whether if the app is being updated without tapping on it (run in background) I think this is a silly way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test Newsstand push during testing simply put this code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES  forKey:@"NKDontThrottleNewsstandContentNotifications"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

In your App Delegate or when you initialize your Newsstand Service. This will ensure that Newsstand-Kit won't throttle your app for notifications (If you don't set this you are limited to 1 push every 8 hours).

I would also recommend you take a loot at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/NewsstandKit_Framework/NewsstandKit_Framework.pdf) for a better overview of Newsstand integration. Its possible that your push notifications are not the expected type for newsstand pushes, they need to have the key content-available with a value of 1. For more info you can read the [Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2280/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011215-CH1-DELIVERING_YOUR_CONTENT-HOW_IS_THE_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_THAT_INITIATES_THE_NEWSSTAND_BACKGROUND_DOWNLOAD_DIFFERENT_FROM_OTHER_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS___WILL_I_HAVE_TO_CHANGE_OR_MODIFY_MY_BACKEND_INFRASTRUCTURE_).

Furthermore, make sure that your actual device has background refresh enabled (assuming iOS 7.0) for your App otherwise Newsstand might not work.